# Synth gives different results depending on the order of predictor names

Tags: r

I'm using the package `Synth` to run synthetic control. Below is an example coming from the docs (`?synth`):

```r
library(Synth)
#> ##
#> ## Synth Package: Implements Synthetic Control Methods.
#> ## See https://web.stanford.edu/~jhain/synthpage.html for additional information.
packageVersion("Synth")
#> [1] '1.1.6'

# load data
data(synth.data)

# create matrices from panel data that provide inputs for synth()
dataprep.out<-
  dataprep(
    foo = synth.data,
    predictors = c("X1", "X2", "X3"),
    predictors.op = "mean",
    dependent = "Y",
    unit.variable = "unit.num",
    time.variable = "year",
    special.predictors = list(
      list("Y", 1991, "mean"),
      list("Y", 1985, "mean"),
      list("Y", 1980, "mean")
    ),
    treatment.identifier = 7,
    controls.identifier = c(29, 2, 13, 17, 32, 38),
    time.predictors.prior = c(1984:1989),
    time.optimize.ssr = c(1984:1990),
    unit.names.variable = "name",
    time.plot = 1984:1996
  )

synth.out <- synth(dataprep.out)
#> 
#> X1, X0, Z1, Z0 all come directly from dataprep object.
#> 
#> 
#> **************** 
#>  searching for synthetic control unit  
#>  
#> 
#> **************** 
#> **************** 
#> **************** 
#> 
#> MSPE (LOSS V): 4.714688 
#> 
#> solution.v:
#>  0.00490263 0.003884407 0.1972011 0.2707289 0.0007091301 0.5225738 
#> 
#> solution.w:
#>  0.0001407318 0.004851527 0.1697786 0.2173031 0.6079231 2.9419e-06

gaps<- dataprep.out$Y1plot-(
  dataprep.out$Y0plot%*%synth.out$solution.w
)
gaps
#>               7
#> 1984 -0.1686325
#> 1985  1.0936597
#> 1986  0.8502235
#> 1987  3.3489866
#> 1988 -1.4241479
#> 1989 -4.1947133
#> 1990 -0.4646250
#> 1991  0.3998366
#> 1992  8.1181380
#> 1993 12.8906031
#> 1994 15.9712216
#> 1995 16.9174715
#> 1996 22.9879423
```

If I change the order of the variables names in `predictors`, I get different results. For instance, if I use `predictors = c("X3", "X1", "X2")`, I obtain the following results, which are different from those above:

```r
#>               7
#> 1984  0.1893536
#> 1985  1.1648763
#> 1986  0.7300337
#> 1987  2.9856265
#> 1988 -1.7695154
#> 1989 -4.0939843
#> 1990 -0.2292420
#> 1991  0.9373385
#> 1992  8.3290952
#> 1993 13.9617721
#> 1994 17.1929960
#> 1995 18.0576735
#> 1996 24.3488169
```

To me, it makes no sense to have different results depending on the order of variables. Can someone explain to me why this is the case? (or confirm that this is a bug?)

Comment: I think it's a bug, I remember a similar issue when using it a while ago. Address the author and put the answer also here, thanks.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I asked the maintainer of the package twice by email but no answer